# Unable to send Emails from Remote Server using asp.net & C#?

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I am able to send emails successfully from LocalHost.
After hosting my website i am unable to send.
The following is the error:

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ha10sm40374374pbc.23 - gsmtp

can anyone help me to solve this.

Below is code:

```
  public void SendMail(string ToMail, string subject, string Message)
        {
                    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
            string fromAddress = "mygmailid@gmail.com";
                    // any address where the email will be sending
            //string toAddress = ToMail;
                    //Password of your gmail address
             const string fromPassword = "********";
                     // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
            //string subject = subject;
             string body = "\n\n"+Message;
                     // smtp settings
                    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                        smtp.Timeout = 20000;

                    }
                    // Passing values to smtp object
                     smtp.Send(fromAddress, ToMail, subject, body);


         }
```

Comment: can you show the code you are using to send email.

Comment: please add smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true and check

Comment: Even after adding UseDefaultCredentials=true also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Google sent a mail with the subjact "Suspicious sign in prevented"
I selected it's me only option.
Then changed the Gmail password and used it in the application .
Now able to send the mails from the production server also...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
              {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(email);
                mailMessage.Subject = "YOUR_SUBJECT";
                mailMessage.Body = "YOUR_MAIL_BODY";

                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("RECIPIENT_EMAILID"));

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new 
                System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = "SENDER_MAIL";
                NetworkCred.Password = "SENDER_MAIL_PASSWORD";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;

                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
             }
```

After invoking above method GOOGLE or GMAIL will send you one mail regarding security (To allow the less secure app to configure mail) then allow that one.